# query to detect ISP violations

Tags: ndepend

I am trying to create a special query with NDepend, but cannot figure it out.

Here's what I'd like to query in a more procedural pseudocode:

```
var list
foreach type t
    foreach i = t.attribute that is an interface
        var nm = i.numberOfMethods
        var mu = numberOfMethods that t actually uses
        if mu / nm < 1
        list.Add(t)
    end foreach
end foreach
return list
```

It's supposed to list types that don't comply with the Interface Segregation Principle.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it means   "t.attribute that is an interface"   an interface is not an attribute class?

Comment: in "numberOfMethods that t actually uses" do you mean "numberOfMethods of i that t actually uses"   Please be precise

Comment: Hey, you're right it's not precise. i = any interface that is used anywhere within the class t (could be a class variable or could be used localy within a method of t). "numberOfMethods that t actually uses" means for example i has 3 methods: A(), B() and C(). Within t only A() and B() are called. So "mu" should equal 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the query you ask can be written this way:

```
from t in JustMyCode.Types where !t.IsAbstract

from i in t.TypesUsed where i.IsInterface

// Here collect methods of i that are not used
let methodsOfInterfaceUnused = i.Methods.Where(m => !m.IsUsedBy(t))
where methodsOfInterfaceUnused.Count() > 0
select new { t, methodsOfInterfaceUnused }
```

This query has the peculiarity to match several time a same type, one for each time `methodsOfInterfaceUnused` is not empty. The result is then nicely presented and understandable:

[image: Segregation Principle with NDepend]

Comment: Actually the second line should look like this: "from i in t.TypesUsed where i.IsInterface && (!i.TypesThatImplementMe.Contains(t))" otherwise it will identify the type that implements i as a type that uses i, which it's not supposed to. But otherwise it works perfect